# Why does my program stop working before entering main()

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sfml

So I woke up today, opened my project up and tried to run it - as luck would have it, it stops before even entering the main function.

However, it worked last night, but doesn't work now. I haven't done anything to change it.

This is `source.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "Game.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    string name;
    cout << "alupigus";

    name = "Dino Attack";

    Game game(800, 800, name);

    game.loadAssets();

    game.Run();

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile and run it in the console, it doesn't show anything but the black screen. I can't enter anything, and the renderwindow from SFML doesn't show up.

I'm only using SFML as an external library, but I didn't modify any links, didn't move its files, etc.

Comment: Try replacing `cout << "alupigus";` with `cout << "alupigus" << endl;`

Comment: not sure how would that help, but i modified it and it doesn't start a new line or anything

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint in to see how far the code actually gets?

Comment: yeah, it stops at the main's first brace

Comment: @noone and when you step forward what happens?

Comment: nothing  http://imgur.com/a/ntL0V

Comment: Looks like you have to take a look at `Game` carefully.

Comment: that's the thing, last night it worked perfectly, and i didn't modify anything between last night when i ran it and closed it, and today when i opened it

Comment: Have you done an system update since the last execution. Maybe a part of the underlying library is broken now. I once had a similar problem with an openGl app, that broke over night and it turned out to be a driver problem, that came with an update.

Comment: Create a simple program using only iostream and let us know if you have the same results.

Comment: i actually do not run into any problems with other programs. additionally, i found (after 2 hours...) the one header/source that cause the problem.however, i'm simply baffled - even without including it, unless i delete it from the program completely, the source simply doesn't enter main(). it works flawlessly otherwise. I could post the code in there here, but it's too much and i dont know if the code itself is a problem, given it worked and i haven't touched it since.

Comment: So it was wrong to say "stop working before entering main()", right? Also, I see no try/catch or anything like that. Programmers often don't bother to check for problems and then encounter big problems that are difficult for others to help with. Also, do you know how to look at the debug output? Also you never answered the question from @const_ref of what happens when you continue from the breakpoint.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't flush stream. Your code should look like this:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "Game.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    string name;
    cout << "alupigus" << endl;

    name = "Dino Attack";

    Game game(800, 800, name);

    game.loadAssets();

    game.Run();

    return 0;
}
```

Also, consider **removing** `using namespace std;`, because this is bad practice in bigger projects. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: In the above code using namespace std is doing nothing harmful to be fair.

Comment: thanks for the tip abot the namespace, but the endl doesn't do anything either, although i'm not really sure what it's supposed to be doing if it doesnt write that string to the console anyway.

Comment: @const_ref I assume that this is kinda greater project, I can't see all code.

Comment: @no one Endl flushes buffer. Please run the debugger and share results.

Comment: @Joel - This is in main.cpp. The include will only affect the code in this file in which case it is doing no harm. Bad practice when included in headers etc. for sure, but in this case it is ok.

Comment: @const_ref Bad practice when included anywhere that's more than a handful of lines long. Seriously, it isn't worth it.

Comment: @Joel it didn't help, it does the exact same thing

Comment: What error causes the crash?

Comment: there is no crash, it just stays there  http://imgur.com/a/ntL0V

Comment: I think it can be SFML library problem. Have you tried to change program entry point to ensure that it doesn't happen in functions called before main?

Comment: i removed the line including sfml in source.cpp entirely as i didn't need it anywhere there, and it didn't help either

Answer (score 1):

Ok so basically I solved the problem.For some reason this prevented the program from running normally, despite me not touching this area of the code for a week

```
x = Board::dinozaurPoz;
        x.x = rand() % 400 + 200;
        while (Board::matrix[(int)x.y / 40][(int)x.x / 40] != 1) {
            x.x = rand() % 400 + 200;
```

the loop wouldn't run indefinitely, so I really don't know what was the problem here. Maybe someone more experienced can advise me on what I did wrong.